# Kafka assigning partitions, do you need to commit offsets

Tags: apache-kafka

Having an app that is running in several instances and each instance needs to consume all messages from all partitions of a topic.

I have 2 strategies that I am aware of:

1. create a unique consumer group id for each app instance and subscribe and commit as usual,
   downside is kafka still needs to maintain a consumer group on behalf of each consumer.
2. ask kafka for all partitions for the topic and assign the consumer to all of those. As I understand there is no longer any consumer group created on behalf of the consumer in Kafka. So the question is if there still is a need for committing offsets as there is no consumer group on the kafka side to keep up to date. The consumer was created without assigning it a 'group.id'.

Answer (score 2):

> ask kafka for all partitions for the topic and assign the consumer to
>   all of those. As I understand there is no longer any consumer group
>   created on behalf of the consumer in Kafka. So the question is if
>   there still is a need for committing offsets as there is no consumer
>   group on the kafka side to keep up to date. The consumer was created
>   without assigning it a 'group.id'.

When you call `consumer.assign()` instead of `consumer.subscribe()` no `group.id` property is required which means that no group is required or is maintained by Kafka.

Committing offsets is basically keeping track of what has been processed so that you dont process them again. This may as well be done manually also. For example, reading polled messages and writing the offsets to a file once after the messages have been processed.

In this case, your program is responsible for writing the offsets and also reading from the next offset upon restart using `consumer.seek()`

The only drawback is, if you want to *move* your consumer from one machine to another, you would need to copy this file also.

You can also store them in some database that is accessible from any machine in case you don't want the file to be copied (though writing to a file may be *relatively* simpler and faster).

On the other hand, if there is a consumer group, so long as your consumer has access to Kafka, your Kafka will let your consumer automatically read from the last committed offset.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be a consumer group setting.  If you're not setting it, whatever consumer you're running will use its default setting or Kafka will assign one.

Kafka will keep track of the offset of all consumers using the consumer group.

There is still a need to commit offsets. If no offsets are being committed, Kafka will have no idea what has been read already.

Here is the command to view all your consumer groups and their lag:

- bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --all-groups

Comment: So then there is basically very little difference from a subscribe with a unique random group id.

Comment: Should each app instance create a unique group.id when assigning, or should they use the same.

Comment: Was trying to understand the assign koncept and read 'Kafka the definitive guide' and the section: 'Standalone Consumer: Why and How to Use a Consumer Without a Group'
at https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html

Comment: consumer groups exist to track separate offsets.  for example, if I have two applications and I want each application to get a full copy of the data, I would have unique consumer groups.  If I have two applications and I want a single copy of the data to be sent, I would use a single consumer group.

Comment: Hi Lars, please accept this answer if your question was answered

Comment: Hi Barry, I will - but there is another answer that seems to contradict your answer - so I am honestly a bit confused.